# How to avoid oscillations when numerically integrating the thermal counductivity equations on discrete grid?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation

Consider the grid (one or two dimensional) of cells modelling the solid - each cell holds the current temperature and heat capacity.

Propagation of heat is then modelled in two iterative steps:
1. Compute temperature differences between neighbour cells thus yielding the heat flux according to the  [Fourier's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier's_law)
2. Compute the termperature changes of cells according to [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) of a cell
3. Proceed to next iteration of time

This kind of approach can lead to oscillations (which cannot happen under heat transfer equation) - when temperature differences are high, heat is transferred too much between cells so they become to have the temperature gradient in reverse direction.

How to avoid such oscillations?

Comment: Presumably the temperature changes calculated in step 2 are of the same order of magnitude or larger than the temperature differences in step 1 leading to oscillation. What happens when the temperature changes in step 2 are much smaller than the temp differences in step 1, say by reducing the iteration interval used?

Comment: Yes, that's how I described it. Temperature difference inverts due to large heat flux.

Comment: So, basically you're computing temperature via an explicit numerical scheme for heat equation. It's known to be unstable if the stability condition on $\frac{\tau}{h^2}$ is violated, where $\tau$ is the time-step (you're using it in your in your iterative process) and $h$ is the space mesh step.

Comment: @VorKir my time step is effectively equals to one (one iteration) and lateral step is also one (one cell), how can that satisfy the stability condition? Is there other than explicit schemes that avoid the unstability?

Comment: Try to introduce weight when computing the new temperature values (equivalent to introducing $\tau \leq 1$),  set tau = 0.1 for example.

Comment: @VorKir this will just postpone the error until sufficient temperature gradient, in case of \tau=0.1 - 10 times larger. There seems to exist already found solution for that, like forward-backward iteration with adjustment.

Comment: First, unless I miss something, your statement is wrong if applied in general, read about stability in any textbook on numerical analysis, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTCS_scheme. Second, I forgot about heat capacity and heat conductivity which affect the stability condition. It should read as $\frac{\tau}{h^2} \leq \frac{c}{2d \lambda}$ where $d = 1,2$ is the dimension, $c$ is the heat capacity and $\lambda$ is the heat conductivity.